# Code does not execute until I exit Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

I am building a script that logs automatically to a site that contains user's shifts for the current week, then extract this data to then later assign the shifts to google calendar.

I wanted to build a GUI for the users to write their credentials so that it can be assigned to the script to be executed.

Main thing I want is that the GUI window will stay open just until the script finishes its whole work.

My problem at the moment is that the script only executes after I close the GUI.

This is my whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
import os
import time
from tkinter import *


excel_shifts_download_url = 'https://app.shiftorganizer.com/excel/rota/125102/?'
download_dir = "C:\\Users\\Python Scripts\\projects\\shifts_script"
driver_path = "C:\\Users\\Python Scripts\\projects\\shifts_script\\chromedriver.exe"
shiftorgnizer_login_url = 'https://app.shiftorganizer.com/login/?lang=he&previous=homepage&greeting=true'

# enabling headless chrome
def setting_chrome_options():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    return chrome_options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=setting_chrome_options()) 


# Site login with user's credentials
company_id = '10'
def site_login():

    driver.get (shiftorgnizer_login_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.find_element_by_id('company').send_keys(company_id)
    driver.find_element_by_id ('username').send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id ('password').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id('log-in').click()
    

# GUI for user to enter his login credentials
def user_credentials():

    global username
    global password 
    username = str(entry_username.get())
    password = str(entry_password.get())
    return username, password
    

root = Tk()
root.title('Shifter')
root.geometry("220x80")
# Text near text box username & password
label_username = Label(root, text='Username')
label_password = Label(root, text='Password')

# Textbox for username & password
entry_username = Entry(root)
entry_password = Entry(root)

# Positioning of text
label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

# Positioning of textboxes
entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Login button
b = Button(root, text='Login', command=user_credentials)
b.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()

# permission to download file via Selenium
def enable_download(driver):
    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd':'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
    driver.execute("send_command", params)

# check if file has been downloaded
def isFileDownloaded():
    file_path = download_dir+"\\schedule.xlsx"
    while not os.path.exists(file_path):
        time.sleep(1)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        print("File Downloaded Successfully")

print('before MAIN')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    enable_download(driver)
    site_login()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("בית | ShiftOrganizer"))
    driver.get('https://app.shiftorganizer.com/app/rota')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("סידור | ShiftOrganizer"))
    driver.get(excel_shifts_download_url)
    isFileDownloaded()
```

I am still working on the google calendar part, this is only part of the script.

Thanks

Comment: Any code after `root.mainloop()` will not run until you close the tkinter application. So if you want something to run before the mainloop, rearrange the order of your code